# Log Actions Latency

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a really modular application in which modules interact with each other for many, many tasks. Lately I have been making some changes to fix some bugs and some processes are now taking longer (not making the application unusable though).

I now want to log the times it takes to perform each action, also taking into account interactions with other objects, to identify where is it taking long. This logging code would most likely be temporary. So, the question is:

How can I write all these actions's latencies (or timeStarted and TimeEnded perhaps) to a single file from all the objects?

Comment: Are you using some Log framework? (don't know about vb compatibility, but I guess you can)

Comment: I am not, which do you suggest?

Comment: If you are coding in .NET then use log4net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be best using a profiling tool such as [Redgate's ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) (they do a 14 day trial).

If you need a logging framework you cannot go wrong with [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Answer (score 1):

I have used [NLOG](http://nlog-project.org/) (free) successfully with VB.NET.  You can define you logging in your code to various levels, and then set which level you want to log to in the config file.  For instance, you may wish to define your logging points as Debug.  You can then set the logging level to Debug whilst you are investigating your issues, and then change it to Error when done.  This allows you to switch extra logging on and off as you need without having to change your code.

I believe that [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) (free as well) also offers similar functionality.